# how to HTML link to external js file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to simply copy and paste the code from this [link](https://gist.github.com/CodeMyUI/357b6275086c0f364344c2f3965b2e80#file-external-scripts), but it seems that the javascript file is not being picked up. The HTML and CSS are working just fine, but I can't seem to link the javascript file. I am not sure why, any help would be appreciated.

Also here is the code linking my js file to the HTML.

```
<script style="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you made sure the paths are correct? Any console errors?

Comment: We'll need to know a little more to help. Open console `<F12>`, copy errors, paste here...

Comment: jquery has to be included before (above) any other javascript. if you place it after you will get `stuff is undefined` errors..

Comment: Sidenote: style is an attribute to write inline css, and type is not required as per html5 standard.

Comment: side-sidentoe: type: is not required either, so that's probably not the problemm

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
<script style="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Change `style` to `type`.

Comment: Stupid mistake, although it didn't change anything.

Comment: What is the issue now? Are you not able to use jQuery in `script.js`?

Comment: When I click the buttons, the js file should execute the code to make the login form transition. But when I click the buttons, nothing happens.

Comment: `$(".info-item .btn").click(function(){
  $(".container").toggleClass("log-in");
});
$(".container-form .btn").click(function(){
  $(".container").addClass("active");
});` <-- js

Answer (score 2):

Should the top line say "type=" and not "style="?

Comment: If you're going to include the `type`, which is not required per the HTML5 spec, it should be `type` and not `style`. You should write your answer more definitively. :)

Comment: @War10ck Will do.

Answer (score 2):

As  can see, the script links very well as I have tested it.
However, please change [the attribute is type not style]

```
<script style="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So did you get the login form to fully function?